# How could I use a method from a Python code in a Java?

Tags: python, java

So I have a Python script that look like this:

```
def methodOne():
    print("Hello I am the first method")

def methodTwo():
    print("Hello I am the second method")
```

And I have a simple Java script like this:

```
public class helloworld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Here I want to call the Methods that are in the Python script
    }

}
```

But I can´t figure out how I could call those methods in the Java file. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/java-working-with-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Runtime. exec() to run python script, As an example first create a python script file using shebang and then set it executable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this my friend https://pythonhosted.org/javabridge/java2python.html it might help you with the solution. But I never tried my self